# Character that projects to a given subgroup

Tags: group-theory, characters

The character of the regular representation $\chi_R$ satisfies

$$\chi_R(g)=\begin{cases} |G| & g=id \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases},$$

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation). In a way, one could say that the character of the regular representation projects the group to the identity subgroup. In this line, is there a generalization where one projects to a generic subgroup? More precisely, exists some representation $\rho_K$ such that

$$\chi_K(g)=\begin{cases} 1 & g\in K \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

for a given subgroup $K\subset G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a character if $K$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. For suppose $\chi$ were a character: take the Frobenius inproduct with the principal character $1_{G}$, then the multiplicity is $\frac{|K|}{|G|}$. This must be a non-negative integer, and this only occurs when $K=G$.

Yet another approach, if it would be a character then it is linear and cannot have values equal to $0$, being a homomorphism to $\mathbb{C}^*$.

The right generalization of the regular character would be the induced character $1_{K}^G$. This is the permutation character of $G$ acting on the right cosets of $K$ by multiplication from the right. The regular character of $G$ is $1_{1}^G$, so the supertrivial character induced to the whole group.

Comment: To check my understanding: is it correct that for a normal subgroup $K\subset G$, $1_K^G(g)=\frac{|G|}{|K|}$ if $g\in K$ and $1_K^G(g)=0$ otherwise?

Comment: Yes this is correct!! If $K$ is not normal that the character is $0$ outside $\bigcap_{g \in G}K^g$, which is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $K$. See also I.M. Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups (https://www.cefns.nau.edu/~falk/classes/511/Isaacs_Character_theory.pdf) Chapter 5.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)